# Обновление ListView в Activity

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Не могу понять, как обновлять ListWiew по таймеру.

```
java.util.Timer timer2 = new java.util.Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rebutmsg();
    }
};
timer2.schedule(task, 10000);
```

Вот функция, что обновляет

```
public void rebutmsg() {

    String s = (String) POST.rebutmsg();
    String[] t = s.split("%");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 59; i++) {
        hm = new HashMap < String, Object > ();

        hm.put(AUTHORKEY, t[i]);
        i++;
        hm.put(TEXTKEY, t[i]);
        i++;
        hm.put(TIMEKEY, t[i]);
        myBooks.add(hm);
    }

    Log.d("TIMER", "  for(i=0; i<=59;i++){");
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        this, 
        myBooks, 
        R.layout.list, 
        new String[] {
            AUTHORKEY, TEXTKEY, TIMEKEY
        }, new int[] {
            R.id.author, R.id.text, R.id.time
        }
    );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

}

Ошибки вылетают после выполнения этой строки

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this, 
    myBooks, 
    R.layout.list, 
    new String[] {
        AUTHORKEY, TEXTKEY, TIMEKEY
    }, new int[] {
        R.id.author, R.id.text, R.id.time
    }
);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> `01-19 08:51:47.991: W/dalvikvm(5319): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb57de278)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1011)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:496)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:425)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at com.fkn.chat.ListviewActivity.rebutmsg(ListviewActivity.java:114)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at com.fkn.chat.ListviewActivity$1.run(ListviewActivity.java:44)
> 01-19 08:51:47.991: E/AndroidRuntime(5319):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)`

Comment: Решил вопрос добавив это в run Таймера.
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.handler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
rebutmsg();
}
}); 
Но теперь другая проблема, таймер срабатывает только раз?? гугл пока что не помогает.

Comment: не рекомендую использовать таймер, имея более универсальный инструмент в андроиде - хендлер

Comment: хорошо, тогда посоветуй пожалуйста как мне обновлять listview, например каждые 5 сек или 10 сек?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
private class Updater extends Thread {
    public boolean stopped = false;

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!stopped) {
                // Активность списка
                SomeActivity.runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
            // Обновление списка
                        }
                    }
                );
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Управление потоком извне:

```
Updater u = new Updater();

u.start();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Можешь один момент: 
SomeActivity.runOnUiThread( - подчеркивает SomeActivity, что это такое и что мне за вместо него написать (помогло просто его убрать)?